# How to disable browser back button in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to prevent user from going to his logged in page after he logs out.Just tried out what I got from internet and its not working, I am still able to go to back page after I log out.How to prevent this?

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
def admin_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("user_login")
```

Comment: if the user has logged out, and the cache is off in the browser, the browser would again hit your view. When this happens, you can put an if condition in there to check if session exists , if not re-route to the desired page.

Comment: The title of the question is irrelevant with what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@login_required` decorator on all the required views will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If the user has logged out, and the cache is off in the browser, the browser would again hit your view when the back button is pressed. When this happens, you can put an if condition in there to check if session exists or not. If not, then re-route to the desired page.

```
if not request.session['username'] :
    #redirect to some page
```